# Django views confusion, two views show same content

Tags: python, django

I have a python django application. I had a view, which I duplicated and changed slightly to create a second view. But they seem to be hooked together and duplicate the page content, when they should be different.

Here is my `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

from . import views

app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [

    # Journals by Discipline
    path('journals-by-discipline/', views.journals_by_discipline, name='journalsByDiscipline'),
    path('journals-by-discipline/chart-data/<str:discipline>/', views.journals_by_discipline_chart_data),
    path('journals-by-discipline/journals-and-disciplines-map/', views.get_journals_and_disciplines_map),
    path('journals-by-discipline/disciplines-list/', views.disciplines_list), 

    # Journals By Discipline (Elsevier)
    path('journals-by-discipline-elsevier/', views.journals_by_discipline_elsevier, name='journalsByDisciplineElsevier'),
    path('journals-by-discipline/chart-data/<str:discipline>/', views.journals_by_discipline_chart_data_elsevier),
    path('journals-by-discipline/journals-and-disciplines-map/', views.get_journals_and_disciplines_map),
    path('journals-by-discipline/disciplines-list/', views.disciplines_list), 
]
```

I have two views, journals_by_discipline and journals_by_discipline_elsevier

Here is my `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
import datetime as datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from urllib.parse import unquote
import json
from .onefigr_analysis import Data

# Instantiate Data object to fetch data across all views
data = Data()


# Journals by Discipline Page

def journals_by_discipline(request):
    template_name = 'app/journals-by-discipline.html'
    return render(request, template_name)

@api_view(['GET'])
def disciplines_list(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response(data.get_disciplines_list())

@api_view(['GET'])
def journals_by_discipline_chart_data(request, discipline):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        query_discipline = unquote(discipline)
        return Response(data.journals_by_discipline_chart_data(discipline)) 

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_journals_and_disciplines_map(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response(data.journals_and_disciplines_map())        



# Journals by Discipline Elsevier Page

def journals_by_discipline_elsevier(request):
    template_name = 'app/journals-by-discipline-elsevier.html'
    return render(request, template_name)   

@api_view(['GET'])
def disciplines_list(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response(data.get_disciplines_list())

@api_view(['GET'])
def journals_by_discipline_chart_data_elsevier(request, discipline):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        query_discipline = unquote(discipline)
        return Response(data.journals_by_discipline_chart_data_elsevier(discipline)) 

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_journals_and_disciplines_map(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return Response(data.journals_and_disciplines_map())
```

In my attempt to create the second view (journals by discipline elsevier), I duplicated the logic used to create the first view. But the result is both pages are the same.

In my Data() class, I have two methods: `journals_by_discipline_chart_data` and `journals_by_discipline_chart_data_elsevier` which are similar but not the same. I am trying to call these differently in my `views.py` file, but it is not working as it should.

How do I unhook these two views?

Answer (score 2):

```
path('journals-by-discipline/', views.journals_by_discipline),
path('journals-by-discipline/chart-data/<str:discipline>/', views.journals_by_discipline_chart_data),

path('journals-by-discipline-elsevier/', views.journals_by_discipline_elsevier),
path('journals-by-discipline/chart-data/<str:discipline>/', views.journals_by_discipline_chart_data_elsevier),
```

The first route in each block is different (`journals-by-discipline/` != `journals-by-discipline-elsevier/`). But the second route is the same (both `journals-by-discipline/chart-data/<str:discipline>/`).

So the route `journals-by-discipline/chart-data/<str:discipline>/` will always call the function `views.journals_by_discipline_chart_data`. It will never reach the second time the route is mentioned.

You could change the second route in the second block to `journals-by-discipline-elsevier/chart-data/<str:discipline>/` to be consistant.

Comment: this is something I needed to correct, thank you.  But I still have the same content for each view